# How to get button's id which was created programmatically in Async Task onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I create adapter in onPostExecute like this, and i set button's id programmatically.

```
list.add(new adapters.GunADP("name","name","name",buttonId));
 //i set button id 5000
```

When i try to getId in end of the onPostExecute method, android don't find that id. And i also can't get that id from onCreate because when app starts that buttun does not exist. 
And i created hackButton for try to get id from hackButton's onClickListener, id returns successfully because onpostexecute method's finished and now that id exist but i don't want to use this way.

```
btn_devam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ileri);
        btn_devam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Button x = (Button) findViewById(5000);
        x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(this, "tag "+v.getTag()+"id "+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
            }
        });
```

So how can i get button's id which i created programmatically after onPostExecute finished?

I want to use this code;

```
    Button x = (Button) findViewById(5000);
```

I cannot use that in oncreate, and also end of the onpostexecute. So how can i get that specific id after that created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved!

I've created thread like this in on create

```
private Thread mMainThread;

mMainThread = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(2000);
                                    try{
        Button x = (Button) findViewById(5000);

        x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(BiletSecim.this, "tag "+v.getTag()+" id "+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                }
                }};
```

Then at the end of onpostexecute method i start the thread

```
mMainThread.start();
```

2000 miliseconds is okay for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the reference of the view that contains that Button.

```
yourView.findViewById("Id to search");
```

yourview is the reference of parent view of your button i.e **V** in your function argument.